# What is the advantage if any of using assert over an if-else condition?

Tags: python, assert

eg x = "hello". Instead of doing assert x == "hello", can I not do a if x != "hello". Is using assert more pythonic?

Comment: `assert` will cause your program to immediately exit with an error if the condition is false.  Is that what you want?

Comment: as @JohnGordon said if you don't want the program to crash and exit with an error message every time the condition is False then use if-else and not assert.

Comment: `assert` statements can be disabled at runtime; the `if` statement cannot. Though both are conditional in nature, they each have distinct, separate use cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assert-stmt), `assert x == "hello"` is equivalent to

```
if __debug__:
    if not (x == "hello"):
        raise AssertionError
```

`__debug__` is a read-only variable that is set to `True` if Python is *not* run with the `-O` flag, and the compiler can omit the assertion check altogether when `-O` is used (rather than constantly checking the value of `__debug__` at run-time).

Use assertions for debugging and testing, to quickly end your program if an assertion fails. Use `if` statements for code that *must* run to enable the rest of your code to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using assert more pythonic?

No. `assert` is for assertions. i.e asserting the value of x should be "hello" and not anything else. It is not a programming logic construct like `if` but a debugging keyword. As the commentors pointed out, when assertion is false, it will throw an `AssertionError` exception (i.e an exceptional thing has happened) and exit the program if not caught.

As @chepner wrote, they can be disabled in runtime if `__debug__` is false, which happens when you execute your code with `-o` flag.

```
python -o myfile.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used an if statement, you would have to write an additional line to explicitly raise the exception. Something like this:

```py
x = "goodbye"

if x != "hello":
  raise AssertionError("x does not equal hello!")
```

But that could be simplified in a much more obvious single line of `assert x == "hello", "x does not equal hello!"`

It's not so bad when you're just looking at a single example, but imagine writing a testing script that checks the return value of dozens of different unit test functions. It's much cleaner to have a single line per assertion:

```py
assert get_user_id("dataguy") == 1, "get_user_id test failed!"
assert get_lat_lon("test_user") == (-71.1,42.2), "get_lat_lon test failed!"
assert register_user("new_user","email") == "success!", "register_user test failed!"
```